# Strategy to open a corrupt csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a bunch of csv files that I am loading in Pandas just fine, but one file is acting up I'm opening it this way :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csv_file)
```

error:

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 1268, in from_csv
>       encoding=encoding,tupleize_cols=False)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 400, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 198, in _read
>       parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 479, in **init**
>       self._make_engine(self.engine)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 586, in _make_engine
>       self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 957, in **init**
>       self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)   File "parser.pyx", line 477, in pandas.parser.TextReader.**cinit**
>   (pandas/parser.c:4434)   File "parser.pyx", line 599, in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas/parser.c:5831)
>   pandas.parser.CParserError: Passed header=0 but only 0 lines in file

To me, this means that there is some sort of corruption in the file, having a quick look is seems fine, it is a big file though and visually checking every single line is not an option, what would be a good strategy to troubleshoot a csv file that pandas won't open ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pandas assigns line 0 as the header. Try calling:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csv_file,header=None)
```

or

```
    df = pd.DataFrame.read_csv(csv_file,header=None)
```

However, it's strange that the files seems to have zero lines (i.e. it's empty). Maybe the filepath is wrong?

Comment: I've doubled checked the file path, it'd definitely right, It's actually reading the file until crashing, I've tried without the using header=None, same issue . Having a closer look at the csv file, it appears that some lines are corrupt, for example the data doesn't match the headers so you end up with a string intead of a date, etc ... is there a way to filter out bad lines using Pandas maybe ?

Comment: I've also tried using :     df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=0, parse_dates=True,error_bad_lines=False) but same problem unfortunately

Comment: Is it possible that there is a line termination issue or a carriage return issue? It looks like you are on a Mac. If you have access to another OS and you can move the .csv file to try there, that might tell you something. It says the file has 0 lines. I'm not sure if this means a single line (as in, the 0th line) or it really means that `pandas` sees it as an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

if in Linux open it with head in the operating system to inspect it then fix it with awk or sed.. if in windows, you could also try vim to inspect and fix it. In short it probably is not best to fix the file in Pandas. You most likely have odd line endings (since the error message  says 0 lines) so heading the file or cat or using Vim is needed to determine the line endings so that you can decide how best to fix or handle.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue like you:

---

> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1_601_g4663353-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in **init**(self, src, **kwds)
>       970         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
>       971 
>   --> 972         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>       973 
>       974         # XXX
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1_601_g4663353-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pandas/parser.so in pandas.parser.TextReader.**cinit** (pandas/parser.c:4628)()
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1_601_g4663353-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pandas/parser.so in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas/parser.c:6068)()
>
> CParserError: Passed header=0 but only 0 lines in file
>
> ---

My code is:

> df = pd.read_csv('/Users/steven/Documents/Mywork/Python/sklearn/beer/data')

Finally, I found I have made a mistake: I sent a path of directory instead of file to **read_csv**.

The correct code is:

> df = pd.read_csv('/Users/steven/Documents/Mywork/Python/sklearn/beer/data/beer_reviews.csv')

It runs right.

So, I think the reason of your issue lies in the file you sent. Maybe it is path of directory just as I have done. Maybe the file is empty  or corrupt, or in wrong encoding set.

I hope the above is helpful to you.